# How can I complete level 5 of Box It! 2 with three stars?

Tags: box-it-2-sokoban

Level 5 of *Box It! 2 Sokoban* can be completed in 114 or fewer steps to get Great Steps (three stars), but the best I've done is something like 120.  I tried writing a level solver but unfortunately the exponential complexity means that (without a much more intelligent algorithm) only much simpler levels can be solved before the heat death of the universe.  Thus I call upon Gaming: How can I beat this step limit?

**Edit:** Adding a screenshot for anyone who'd like to give it a try without actually having the game.  Goal is to get the blocks into the brown squares, the bushes/flowers act like walls, and you can't push multiple blocks.  (Ignore the extra on-screen controls, it's a composite image.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is your current best pattern. I can get 117 on this level so maybe we can combine ideas to streamline it the most.

Comment: @nhutto Unfortunately I got it a while ago and wasn't able to reproduce it, recently I haven't done so well.

Comment: Should this question have a tag identifying the game, or at least a mention in the text?

Comment: @NateEldredge Tags are removed automatically if not enough questions are asked that use that tag.  I added the game name to the title, thanks :)

Comment: Got it.  I guess that's the downside of this site's convention that the game is usually only identified in the tag.